# iOS/Xib: Easiest way to show a button in the middle of different iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, xib

In my iOS app, I just want to have a button located in the middle of screens of multiple devices (like iPhone 6, iPhone SE, iPad Air).

However, surprisingly, it seems not intuitive to do (at least not as Android) in XCode + Xib.

Following shows a trivial example of this problem where I put the button aligned to the middle:
[image]

However, unless the "dimension" of the view is set identical to fit the installed device, there is no way to display the button in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add horizontal and vertical center constraints as follows and it will always keep your button at center of any screen as shown in the image below
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Yu-Chih: Happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add distance constraints to borders of the screen :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMWZ6.png)